# Why does doing a restart, not restart?

Tags: 12.04, restart

I press the power button on my laptop, press restart, but my computer only shuts off and doesn't really restart.  Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What model is your laptop?, some specifications might be useful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the model of your laptop or its specifications, the only preliminary thing I can suggest, which has worked for me before, is to try a kernel boot parameter such as `reboot=bios`, however this will only work on X86 32 bit systems.

This approach is also mentioned on the [Ubuntu wiki for Grub 2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Fixing_reboot.2BAC8-shutdown_freezes), and can often work, and please see the note there about an alternative boot parameter, especially for some Dell systems, called `reboot=pci`.

Now edit `/etc/default/grub` (if you don't use `vim`, replace it with another editor):

```
sudo vim /etc/default/grub
```

Make sure that you add your kernel boot parameter so that you have a line identical to this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash reboot=bios"
```

Now you **must** run

```
sudo update-grub
```

for the changes to be incorporated in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

More details on such kernel boot parameters are explained in `man bootparam` or the [Ubuntu manpages online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man7/bootparam.7.html). However the most detailed documentation is in the `linux-doc` package, and when that is installed you will have `/usr/share/doc/linux-doc/kernel-parameters.txt.gz`. However, for a description of the other options such as `reboot=acpi` you need to install the kernel source and look at the file that `kernel-parameters.txt.gz` directs you to. Alternatively, a quick summary of other options are listed [in this article](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/reboot-ubuntu-reboot-good-dog.html).

As an extra note, the kernel log often contains recommendations such as `If system does not work as expected, please boot with acpi=copy_dsdt`. To find any such errors, grep the kernel log with

```
grep -Ei 'ACPI Error|ACPI BIOS Bug' /var/log/kern.log
```

If the problem persists, it may be specific to your hardware and need to be reported as an acpi bug against the kernel.